# Problem using make_regression function in sklearn

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

using sklearn to make a sample dataset , but if assigning `n_feature>1` it produces an error of `x and y must be the same size`.

```
x,y=make_regression(n_samples=150, n_features=2,noise=20)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()

Error: "x and y must be the same size"
```

Note: x and y are the same size.

Comment: Hello, please don't provide images for code or error messages.  They should be included as text in your question.   Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help pages.  You should edit your question to make it easier/possible to respond to.

Comment: You should show the entire error message since they are often helpful.  For your specific issue, after `make_regression`, what dimensions does `x` have? ... and what do you want to plot?

Comment: Obviously, for `n_features=k` with `k>1`, `x` and `y` are **not** of the same size: `x` is a 2D array of size `(n_samples, k)` while `y` is a 1D array of size `(n_samples,)`. Scatter plots (which your error is actually about, and not `make_regression`) work only for 2 1D arrays, and will expectedly fail to work if any of the arrays is a 2D one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `x` and `y` are **NOT** the same size. and that's because you set `n_feature = 2` so when you print `shape` this would be like this:

```
>>> print(x.shape)
(150, 2)
>>> print(y.shape)
(150,)
```

So, you can use a scatter plot only with `n_features = 1`.